# sort by using a member of an object in c++

Tags: c++

I'd like to use sort() to do the following

- I have a text char[] T which is (private) member of a class. The text has length n.
- I also ave an array int[] P that contains the first n integers.

I'd like to std::sort P such that the lexicographic order among suffixes of T are preserved
i.e., for any `i < j` we have that `T[P[i]...n]` is lex smaller than `T[P[j]...n]`.

I'm able to do it when `char[] T` is a global variable by defining

```
bool myfunction (int i,int j) { 
  int m = i, l = j;
  while(m<n and l <n) {
      if(T[m] != T[l]) return (T[m]<T[l]);
      m++; l++;
  }
  return (m<l);
}
```

and calling `std::sort(P, P+n, myfuction)`

I'm in truble when `T` is a member of an object (and sort is called by a method of that object).

How can I define `myfunction` so that `T` is visible? 
Should it be member of that object? If yes, how?
Thank you very much.

Edit: bool instead of int

Comment: I have edited the question for clarity, you can click on the edit button to see the changed performed, basically: items start with " - ", and need a leading empty line. You can format code inlined in the text with backticks \`, and you can format blocks of code by selecting the block and clicking on the `{}` button.

Comment: What version of `sort` are you using? That is not `std::sort`, or if it is you are using it in an awfully wrong way...

Answer (score 2):

As you guessed, one way to do it is by defining yourfunction() as a public member of that class.

Example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class T
{
private:
    int value;
public:
    T()
    {
        value = rand() % 100;
    }

    static bool Compare(const T &a, const T &b)
    {
        return a.value < b.value;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    vector<T> data;

    //add some data
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        data.push_back(T());

    //sort using static method that can access private attributes
    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), T::Compare);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `sort` represents `std::sort`, the function that you are using as predicate is wrong for a couple of reasons, the first of which is that the returned type from the function should be a `bool` and not an `int`.

The next thing that is wrong is that the predicate is required to be consistent, that is, given two inputs `a` and `b` the result of `predicate( a, b )` must be either true or false and always the same. If that condition is not met, the result of calling `sort` will be undefined, possibly including an infinite loop.

The approach (rather than the predicate itself) is probably not good either, as the number of times that the predicate will be called depends on the input data, and the results of the different calls to the predicate (until the algorithm thinks, that according to your partial order, the sequence is sorted).

Comment: Yes, I wrote the function as if it was c and qsort. 
Of course, the problem in my code was not due to that bool/int typo.

Comment: The predicate is correct. Any call to myfuction is refering  always to the same text T. Thus, it is consistent and produces the correct sorted output. My problem is that I'm not able to refer T whenever it is member of an object.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a functor object:

```
struct myfunctor {
    const char *T;
    size_t n;
    myfunctor(const char *T, size_t n) : T(T), n(n) {}
    bool operator()(int i, int j) {
        // stuff using T and n
    }
    // Optionally, something along these lines, I haven't tested it
    template <size_t N> myfunctor(const char (&x)[N]) : T(&x[0]), n(N) {}
    template <size_t N> myfunctor(char (&x)[N]) : T(&x[0]), n(N) {}
};

SomeObjectContainingT x;
std::sort(P, P+n, myfunctor(x.T, x.n));
```

Or if `x.T` is an actual array rather than just a pointer, the template constructors will capture the array size from the type, no need for a second parameter:

```
std::sort(P, P+n, myfunctor(x.T));
```

Edit: sorry, missed that T is private. I think you have two issues here, scope and accessibility. The functor solves the scope problem, now for the accessibility.

If you want external functions to access T, `x` must provide a means to access it. For example, it could return the functor object:

```
class SomeObjectContaining T {
    char T[23];
  public:
    myfunctor comparator() { return myfunctor(T); }
};

std::sort(P, P+n, x.comparator());
```

Or you could mess about with `friend`: define your functor class as a `friend` of SomeObjectContainingT, then pass the object to its constructor rather than the array.